# Convert all type of parentheses in emacs latex to \left \right form

Tags: emacs, latex, elisp

In my .emacs I have the following function

```
;; Put the point immediately after a closing paren. replace-matching-parens will
;; replace the closing ) with \right) and the matching start paren ( with
;; \left(.
(defun replace-matching-parens ()
  (interactive)
  (save-excursion
  (let ((end-point (point)))
    (backward-list)
    (let ((start-point (point)))
      (goto-char end-point)
      (re-search-backward ")" nil t)
      (replace-match " \\\\right)" nil nil)
      (goto-char start-point)
      (re-search-forward "(" nil t)
      (replace-match "\\\\left( " nil nil)))))
```

bound to a key to replace matching occurences of ( and ) with \left( and \right). How can I extend this to also work for pairs of [ ] and { } such that they are replaced by \left[ and \right] resp. \left{ and \right}.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should get you started.  Essentially, to use `backward-list` you need to give the other chars  (`][}{`) the syntax of open and close parentheses temporarily.  And then you need to adjust the search and replace to use those chars, not just regular parens.

```
(eval-when-compile (require 'cl))   ; case

(defun replace-matching-parens (char)
  (interactive (list (char-before)))
  (unless (memq char '(?\) ?\] ?\}))
    (error "Cursor is not after `)', `]', or `}'"))
  (save-excursion
    (let ((syntable   (copy-syntax-table (syntax-table)))
          (end-point  (point)))
      (modify-syntax-entry ?\[ "(" syntable)
      (modify-syntax-entry ?\] ")" syntable)
      (modify-syntax-entry ?\{ "(" syntable)
      (modify-syntax-entry ?\} ")" syntable)
      (with-syntax-table syntable
        (backward-list)
        (let ((start-point  (point)))
          (goto-char end-point)
          (search-backward (format "%c" char) nil t)
          (replace-match (format " \\\\right%c" char) nil nil)
          (goto-char start-point)
          (search-forward (format "%c" (setq newchar  (case char
                                                        (?\) ?\( )
                                                        (?\] ?\[ )
                                                        (?\} ?\{ ))))
                          nil t)
          (replace-match (format "\\\\left%c " newchar) nil nil))))))
```